# monthpicker is not working in ext5.1.0

Tags: extjs

I am using this month picker (http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?148368-EXT4-monthfield-with-month-picker-for-Extjs4).

And everythings all right when it was ext-5.0.1. However, once I upgrade it to ext-5.1.0, The month picker is no longer working, as everytime I click any month or year, the picker window disppear and don't pick anything for me.

It there any solution which allow me to use this monthpicker? Or can someone provide another similar month picker?

Comment: According to the thread title - it was designed for extjs 4

Comment: I know it was designed for extjs 4 and it worked fine previously.
The problem appears after I have upgraded to extjs 5.1.0 so I wonder if anything could be done to make it also works on extjs 5.1.0

Comment: "if anything could be done" --- you could rewrite it

Comment: I would say this is a correct but not helpful answer because if I am capable to rewrite it, I would not have to ask here.

Comment: It works: http://jsfiddle.net/gj3p0e1m/1/

Comment: re Lolo: There exist my problem that the panel disappear if I click it